# Using function to minimize the amount of code

Tags: python

I have a problem with my Python program. Let's say, I want to ask what is their favorite number between 1 and 100 to my students. So, I asked John and he replied that his is 1. Again, I asked Mark and he came up with 50 and so on. And then I also want to know their gender as well. Let's say John is a boy and Mark is a boy too. And I have 10 students in my class. What I want to do is keep a record like:

```
<John - 1 - boy>
<Mark - 50 - boy>
```

So, I wrote some code like this:

```
while True:
    try:
        john_n = (int(input('Enter your favourate number : ')))
        if john_n >= 100 or john_n <= 0:
            print('Error!')
            continue
        else:
            john_n = str(john_n)
            break
    except ValueError:
        continue

while True:
    try:
        john_g = (str(input('Are you boy or girl? : ')))
        if john_g == 'boy':
            std_g = 'boy'
            break
        elif john_g == 'girl':
            john_g = 'girl'
            break
        else:
            print('Please only answer \'boy\' or \'girl\'')
            continue
    except ValueError:
            print('Please only answer \'boy\' or \'girl\'')
            continue

print(str('John\n'+'Fav No. '+john_n+'\nGender '+john_g))
```

It works, kind of. But I have another 9 students to go. I want to do it more effectively. So how can I do it? How to do it more effectively?

Comment: As you said in the title, define a function to do it, and call the function for each student. What problem are you having? Defining functions is one of the basic programming skills you need to learn.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What actually is the difficulty here? For example, are you able to write and use a function *at all*?

Comment: Suggest you read [Keep data out of your variable names](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html).

Answer (score 1):

The reason you need so much code is due to the way you're storing the information — namely differently named variables for each one — requires writing code specific to each one of them. To truly minimize the code need to solve the problem (for *any* number of students) is to store the data in a different manner — which will make it relatively easy to write a generic function for entering the information for any one of them.

In the code below the info for each student is stored in a list of instances of a "`dataclass`" named `Student` which can easily be defined using Python's [`dataclasses`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#module-dataclasses) module — a utility to make structured classes specially for storing data which was added in version 3.7 (see [PEP 557](https://peps.python.org/pep-0557/)).

Once that's done, then writing a function like you want (`get_student_info()` in the code below) is a relatively simple matter because all it has to do is gather three pieces of information and pass them back to the caller.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Student:
    """Class for keeping track of student's favorite number and gender."""
    name: str
    favorite: int
    gender: str


def get_student_info():
    """Prompt user for pieces of information needed to create an instance of the
    Student class and return it as a tuple.
    """
    name = input("Please enter student's name or just the Enter key to quit: ")
    if not name:
        return None  # Terminate data entry.

    while True:
        try:
            favorite = int(input('Please enter their favorite number between 1 and 100: '))
        except ValueError:
            print('sorry, that is not a valid integer')
            continue

        if 1 <= favorite <= 100:
            break
        else:
            print('Number is not in range of 1 to 100, please try again')
            continue

    while True:
        gender = input('Please enter their gender identity ("boy" or "girl"): ')
        if gender in ("boy", "girl"):
            break
        else:
            print('Sorry, that is not an acceptable gender identity, please try again')

    return name, favorite, gender


# Create a list of Students.
students = list()

print('Enter student information for list\n')
while True:
    info = get_student_info()
    print()
    if not info:
        break
    students.append(Student(*info))

print()
print('Student list created:')
for i, student in enumerate(students, start=1):
    print(f'{i}: {student}')
```

Sample usage:

```
Enter student information for list

Please enter student's name or just the Enter key to quit: John
Please enter their favorite number between 1 and 100: 1
Please enter their gender identity ("boy" or "girl"): boy

Please enter student's name or just the Enter key to quit: Mark
Please enter their favorite number between 1 and 100: 50
Please enter their gender identity ("boy" or "girl"): boy

Please enter student's name or just the Enter key to quit:


Student list created:
1: Student(name='John', favorite=1, gender='boy')
2: Student(name='Mark', favorite=50, gender='boy')
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function that handles the repeated prompting for input matching a given condition by passing the condition in (as a function) along with the input prompt and the error message to show them if the condition isn't met:

```
def prompt_with_condition(prompt, condition_func, error):
    while True:
        result = input(prompt)
        try:
            if condition_func(result):
                return result
        except ValueError:
            pass
        print(error)
```

To handle all the students, I'd suggest just doing a loop over all of their names:

```
for name in ['John']:  # add the rest of the names here!
    number = prompt_with_condition(
        'Enter your favourite number : ',
        lambda n: 0 < int(n) < 100,
        "Error!"
    )
    gender = prompt_with_condition(
        'Are you boy or girl? : ',
        ('boy', 'girl').__contains__,
        "Please only answer 'boy' or 'girl'"
    )
    print(name)
    print(f"Fave No. {number}")
    print(f"Gender {gender}")
```